# TypeScript - how to type a function that can take any number of args that are either strings or numbers?

Tags: typescript

I want to type a function that returns strings based on any number of args that could be either strings or numbers. I tried:

```
type StringGetter = (...args: (string | number)[]) => string;
```

but when I create a function:

```
const func: StringGetter = (input: string) => "something";
or
const func: StringGetter = (input1: number, input2: string) => "something";
```

I get an error like:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I understand that this is happening because I defined the type such that TypeScript thinks I want a function that can have any number of args, each arg being able to accept both numbers **AND** strings. How do I type it such that it represents a function that can have any number of args, each arg being either a string **OR** a number (or either)?

Example:

I would like to have a type `StrnigGetter` such that the following are ok:

```
const func: StringGetter = (x: string) => "something";
const func: StringGetter = (x: number) => "something";
const func: StringGetter = (x: string, y: number) => "something";
const func: StringGetter = (x: string, y: string) => "something";
const func: StringGetter = (x: number, y: number) => "something";
```

but the following are not:

```
const func: StringGetter = (x: boolean) => "something";
const func: StringGetter = (x: any) => "something";
```

Comment: If you declare your type like that you will always have to accept both inputs

Comment: Right, I see that now, so how can I define it such that I can create functions that accept either or both? Is it not possible?

Comment: like this you mean? `type StringGetter<T> = (...args: (T)[]) => string;`

Comment: _each arg being either a string OR a number (or either)_ - it won't be compatible with implementation `(input: string) => ...` as it expects first argument to be a string. You'll need to change it to `(input: string | number) =>

Comment: @Ric almost, but doing that would end up requiring all the parameters to be of the same type, right? I would like the parameters to be of either string or number (mixed).

Comment: @Bill yep you got it, its a lot wider than you asked for, but, it just demonstrates the use of generics to allow any given type to be considered.

Comment: @Bill the requirement is problematic, because it will allow calling the function with wrong parameters and it will blow up at runtime (e.g `const func: StringGetter = (x: string, y: number) => x.toLowerCase(); ` but you allowed to call it as `func(123)`)

Comment: @AlekseyL. but it doesn't complain when I do - type StringGetter = (...args: any[]) => string; - which is pretty close to what I want, but I want to specify that these functions can only have parameters that are strings or numbers, not anything. is that not possible?

Comment: It doesn't complain, but it is wrong thing to do (explained above why)

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics like

```
type StringGetter<T extends string | number> = (...args: T[]) => string;

const func1: StringGetter<string> = (input: string) => "something";
const func2: StringGetter<number> = (input: number) => "something";
```

Comment: my thinking exactly, nice one

Comment: This would require the inputs to be all of the same type, right? I would like it to be able to accept mixed inputs, such as:

const func: StringGetter = (input1: number, input2: string) => "something";

Comment: Pay attention this is unsound - for some reason it allows assigning function that requires one argument to type that can be invoked without arguments and can cause error at runtime (`func1()`). So it better be something like `type StringGetter<T extends string | number> = (...args: [T, ...T[]]) => string;`

Answer (score 0):

```
type GenericStringGetter<T extends string | number> = (...args: T[]) => string;
type StringGetter = GenericStringGetter<string> | GenericStringGetter<number>;

const funcs: StringGetter = (input: string) => "something";

const funcn: StringGetter = (input: number) => "something";
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this doesn't allow mixed parameter types? eg I want the following to be acceptable - const func: StringGetter = (x: string, y: number) => "something";